# no error, but findviewbyid does not resolve

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get id from my `xml`, I cant find any `error` but the `findviewbyid` is not resolve

Here is my `java` (main activity)

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button0, button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6,
        button7, button8, button9, buttonAdd, buttonSub, buttonDivision,
        buttonMul, button10, buttonC, buttonEqual;
EditText exampleEditText;

float mValueOne, mValueTwo;

boolean exampleAddition, mSubtract, exampleMultiplication, exampleDivision;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
```

And here is my `xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relative1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edt1"
    android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
    android:text="2" />
```

The rest of the `buttons` are same, just my code is too long to post all.

I am not sure if its my import error or?
Any idea?

Comment: Try cleaning the project and build again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android `Java` and `XML` bind on following code

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

1. Check your Activity file name
2. Try Build -> Clean Project then rebuild when it finishes